# Asus zenphone 2 USB debugging

Tags: android, adb

So, I have asus zenphone 2 that I want to use for usb debugging.
However android studio does not show my asus device even when its connected through usb.

I downloaded asus usb drivers for windows from [here](https://www.asus.com/in/Phones/ZenFone_2_ZE551ML/HelpDesk_Download/)

However there's no exe file in downloaded zip, So i have installed the driver by going to Device manager > add legacy hardware > choose driver directory.

However device manager shows following error 
"Asus Android ADB Interface" - This device cannot start. (Code 10)

I have pc link and that works perfectly.

Does any one has idea what can be done. I am on windows 7

Comment: Likely either try a generic adb driver which can be configured for your device or better yet stop trying to use windows as a platform for android development - it is by far the least suitable of the three nominally supported platforms.

Comment: Generic driver? where to get ? any link or tutorial ? About windows, yeah it may not be best, but i am not a linux guru, i would like to stay with windows till i get my mac in few months

Comment: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-make-truly-universal-adb-and.html